# cannot login and register using volley in android

Tags: php, android

I am making a login and registration page in android using volley for posting the data and im having a problem where the home activity cannot start

This is the android code and the php script

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Matching server responce message to our text.
                    if (ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {


                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));

                    }
                    else {

                        // Showing Echo Response Message Coming From Server.
                        Toast.makeText(LoginForm.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    // Finish the current Login activity.
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                    Toast.makeText(LoginForm.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
```

this is the php code that handles the posts from the android application

```
 <?php

 require "connection.php";
// Check whether username or password is set from android   
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$Sql_Query = "select * from login_and_registration where username = 
'$username' and password = '$password'";

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$Sql_Query));

if(isset($check)){

echo "Data Matched";
}
else{
echo "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again !";
}

}else{
echo "Check Again";
}``
mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>r code here

Comment: post crash log ?

Comment: sorry i dont understand?

Comment: is your app crashing? like app unfortunately stopped working?

Comment: no its not crashing at all

Comment: Then what is the problem you are having? Have you tested your web service? If you haven't, try testing it with postman. And make sure you have added internet permission in manifest.

Comment: alright thanks i will do that. The internet permission is there though so thanks for that i will test the webservice

Comment: Thank you it was definitely the web service checked it and its now working fine

Comment: Glad you got it working